# I want to know how I can wait for a return function to send data before executing the next line of code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a bit of a problem with my code(Node.js). I want have 2 files app.js and state.js, i basically created the two to try and solve the issue i am having.

on the second file "State.js" i have a function that returns an object and i delayed the return by 10 secs (With impression of a slow internet, etc). and i am trying to retrieve the object in the app.js file. but at the moment, it doesn't work. I have tried using promise (async & await) but that returns an error on the terminal, i also tried running a setInterval to monitor the variable i which to use in retrieving the object to only execute when it has data but that doesn't work as well. Please I need assistance as soon as possible.

Below is the code examples for the 2 scenario.

=========================== state.js file =======================

```
function test(val){
    setTimeout(() => {
        return {
            code: 0,
            value: val
        }
    }, 10000);
}

module.exports = test;
```

========================== app.js file (Using the promise approach)============================

```
async function runNow(){
    let v = await t('some string');
    console.log(v.value)
}

runNow();
```

================================== app.js (using the interval approach) ==========

```
function runNow(){
    let engine = setInterval(() => {
        let v = t('some string');
        if(v === null || v === undefined){
            console.log(v);
        }else{
            clearInterval(engine);
            console.log(v.value);
        }
    }, 5000);
    // console.log(v.value);
}

runNow();
```

Comment: returning a value in setTimeout is pointless, the value goes nowhere - `the promise approach` requires that you have a Promise to await - you don't

Comment: @bravo what do you suggest i do? and how do i create a promise

Comment: see: [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use promise or callback to accomplish what you're wanting to do here.

If I return something from the `callback` fucntion of  `setTimeout(callback, time)` it actually doesn't get returned by the `setTimeout` funciton.

The implementation of `setTimeout` is probably similar to something like this.

```js
function setTimeout(callback, time, ...args) {
    // After the given time it executes the callback
    callback(...args);
}
```

The desired implementation of your state.js file would be like the following:

```js
function testWithPromise(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        code: 0,
        value: val,
      });
    }, 5000);
  });
}

function testWithCallback(val, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback({
      code: 0,
      value: val,
    });
  }, 3000);
}

// export the function


// use it in other modules as
testWithCallback("callback_approach", console.log);
testWithPromise("promise_approach").then(console.log);

// or with an async function
async function getValue() {
  const value = await testWithPromise("async_promise");
  console.log(value);
}

//getValue();
```

Comment: You're most welcome. It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a promise in order for `await` to wait for it

Try:

```js
function test(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({code: 0, value: val});
    }, 10000);
  });
}

async function runNow() {
  let v = await test('someString');
  console.log(v.value);
}
```